How to change the Camera position for Google Maps Composable using a UK postcode or address
Is there a way to convert a String which could hold a UK postcode to a LatLng object that can be used to change the camera Position on the android application using Google Maps Android SDK?
Tried looking through android developers for any documentation however it isn't for Android SDK.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Consider using the Geocoding API
You can restrict the region to the UK (GB) and just use the postcode as the address query string.  For example,
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=WC2A&region=gb&key=
